# Using dropdown to update content of tables in retool

Tags: postgresql, dropdown, retool

I am new to retool and postgres.
I want to keep 2 values in my drop down, so that when I select 1, I get columns of only for 1 device in the table.

I tried using the following query:

```
IF {{select1.value=='2021_1_1'}} 
THEN
select * from device WHERE device_id='2'
ELSE 
SELECT * from device WHERE device_id='1
```

but it is giving me the following error:
**error:true
message:"syntax error at or near "IF""
position:1**

please help.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use device_id in Values section of your drop-down, so you'll be able to modify your query to something like this:

```
select * from device where device_id = {{select1.value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `where` clause to your SQL statement to express this condition. This is only useful if the value in your Select component is the same value by which you want to filter your table.

By default, this type of SQL query will also be set to "run automatically when inputs change" which means that when the user changes their selection in the dropdown component, the query will re-run with the new filter set.

Here's an example:

```
select * from device where device_id = {{ select1.value }}
```

Note that the Select component has different values for the `value` and the `display value` (aka the `label`), which means you can display a different value to the user vs. the value passed the query.